# Using bayes formula

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose a corpus contains 300,000 word-tokens and 70,000 of these are tagged as N (common noun). The word-form house occurs 1,000 times in the corpus, and it is tagged either as N or V. Analysis shows that house accounts for 0.4% of all common noun tokens in the corpus.  Use Bayes’ formula to calculate the probability that a given occurrence of house is tagged as N.

Answer (score -1):

Let $H$ be the event that a given word is house, and $N$ be the event that a given word is a common noun.  We want to find $P(N|H)$.

According to Bayes Theorem,

$$P(N|H) = {P(H|N)P(N)\over P(H)}$$

We know that

$P(H|N) = .004$,

$P(N) = {70,000\over 300,000} = {7\over 30}$

and $P(H) = {1,000\over 300,000} = {1\over 300}$

Plugging these values into the equation gets you $P(N|H) = 0.28$

Comment: You should provide *help* on how to solve the problem, not to do everything.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I don't understand why you downvoted my answer.